# Is it possible to just pour epoxy on wood to make a shower tray?

Tags: shower, waterproofing, epoxy, kerdi

I need to build a shower real quick, so I am about to use Kerdi boards to do that. I do not have the time to tile (and not the funds to have someone make it), so I was wondering if I could just use the Kerdi curb and pour epoxy on the wood base (while the drain pipe is plugged and sealed on the sides obviously) to make a waterproof tray myself as long as the epoxy reaches the kerdi boards on all walls and the curb.

I find the off-the-shelf pans very expensive for what they are, and this would actually give me a perfect seal at the same time for half the cost.

Comment: If you need a shower quickly without tiling, fiberglass/acrylic showers are made, and are fast & waterproof...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my question

Comment: if you don't have time to tile why are you putting in Kerdi? how are you going to finish the walls?

Comment: I was planning on laying a vinyl roll but I don't like the fact that it's toxic past 60°C so I'd probably just glue acrylic panels instead - there are cheap 48x96in ones

Comment: If you use epoxy, how will you slope it so water runs downhill into the drain?  I agree with @Ecnerwal,  fiberglass/acrylic showers are a good way to go and they are easier to clean than tile.

Comment: My concern with epoxy is without tile to spread the load of a person standing on it it will probably crack, I understand this is on a floor but I have seen many DIY jobs that did not last because of the flex in the floor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can absolutely not do this.

1. Foremost, epoxy is somewhat brittle and you will end up with cracks in it very quickly.
2. As others noted, a shower floor must be sloped to drain.
3. It will be slippery.
4. It will not pass any inspection and will be a major impediment to selling the house.

Answer (score 2):

There is one answer to your question highlighted with 4 upvotes (at this time) that is extremely "Tiger Mommy".

Yes, you can do an epoxy shower floor but you need to reinforce the substrate with fiberglass mesh.  I have done this.

1. First you prime your substrate. Use a high-solids flat paint or a marine paint.
2. Then you pour a bond coat of epoxy and lay the fiberglass mesh on that.  Work the bond coat into the fiberglass mesh until the fiberglass gets a little bit translucent.
3. After that is set, you are ready for your build coats of epoxy.  You can paint over a sanded bond coat or dye your build coats for color or translucency (most people don't find fiberglass mesh attractive).
4. To maintain your slope you should let your epoxy start to set a bit and that way it won't flow too much.  It's still going to want to flow when you torch the bubbles but use your v-notch trowel to bring the material back where you need it.
5. For this application you will probably need to add a grip agent in the final coat.  Leaving a pure epoxy surface will be slicker than snot.

Don't be afraid to experiment.  After all, you will end up with a water proof shower.  Your patience and determination will prove out the results.

Comment: Almost like building a fiberglass boat! However, "patience and determination" don't jibe well with the "quick and dirty and cheap" that the OP was looking for. I mean, if he didn't have time to tile, he sure doesn't have time for all this... Despite all those impractical objections, you still get a +1!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to seal a shower floor using paint-on membranes, and glass fibre bandages.

With poured epoxy the seal between the walls and floor is critical, but the Kerdi corner sealing product should work in these horizontal corners as well as it works in vertical corners.

Comment: Hi Jasen, thanks for the answer. I don't really understand - I thought sealing was much less of an issue with epoxy pouring, i.e. it's easy to seal just for epoxy (more viscous than water) and after it's cured it's pretty much a bulletproof seal with whatever it touched. I'm actually asking if I need anything else other than epoxy pouring to achieve a good seal with the walls, meaning can I just pour epoxy on bare wood.

Comment: Did you mean the epoxy would be the finished surface of the shower or did you imagine putting tile on it?

Comment: I imagined simply pouring the epoxy and calling it a day, given that it's self-levelling. Of course with this method a curb is mandatory, but it feels so much simpler.

Comment: You need a slope for a shower floor.